# How to edit and list an API fetch in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I am new to react. The API call returns names separated by slashes like john/smith/doe/richard. I want to list the names on different lines like:

- john
- smith
- richard
  Is this possible to do? I am using axios to invoke the remote API.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert your data to array by using `split` method and then render your array by `map`, like this:

```
 <ul>
      { data.split("/").map(name=> <li key={name}> {name}</li>) }
  </ul>
```